# Why do we start with 0 rep in Unikong?

Tags: discussion, unikong

In Unikong, we start the game with 0 reputation. Compared to the standard of starting with 1 rep on Stack Overflow, this doesn't make sense.

[image]

Why is the starting amount of 0 rep chosen?

Comment: You have to register in the game to get 1 rep. If you are not doing that first, you are playing the game wrong...

Comment: Tag should clearly be *bug*, not *discussion*.

Comment: Why do we die from downvotes instead of losing rep in Unikong?

Comment: I don't know where else to put this but, for the record, Unikong is _excellent_. Well done!

Comment: It should sync up with Jon's reputation.

Comment: Because Jon Skeet was the only one to start with 0 rep instead of 1

Comment: I can tell people that programmers start counting at zero again.

Comment: any docs about playing the above game? Got dead whenever I try to ride unicorn from frontside or rearside.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The mere act of choosing to affiliate yourself with Stack Overflow is something that enhances your reputation.  The same cannot be said of this game.  In fact, perhaps you should start lower than 0.

Answer (score 30):

The 100 rep you would normally get goes directly to Jon Skeet. And you should thank him for that.

Comment: You mean 101 right?

Comment: @PythonMaster No, you _start_ with 1 rep and then you _get_ 100.

Comment: Why thank Jon skeet?